# Mongo query: $exist NULL value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following object in a Mongo collection:

```
{ 
    "active" : true,
    "startDate": Date( 1434355148265 ), // Mon Jun 15 2015 15:59:08 GMT+0800 (HKT)
    "endDate": null,
    "lastFeedSearch": null,
    "lastTopicSearch": null
}
```

I then try to run the following query, but it doesn't seem to return any objects

```
{  
   "active":true,
   "$and":[  
        {  
         "$or":[  
            {  
               "startDate":{  
                  "$exists": false
               }
            },
            {  
               "startDate":{  
                  "$lte": "2015-06-16T07:07:30+00:00"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "$or":[  
            {  
               "endDate":{  
                  "$exists": false
               }
            },
            {  
               "endDate":{  
                  "$gte": "2015-06-16T07:07:30+00:00"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "$or":[  
            {  
               "$or":[  
                  {  
                     "lastTopicSearch":{  
                        "$lte": "2015-06-16T06:07:30+00:00"
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "lastTopicSearch":{  
                        "$exists": false
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "$or":[  
                  {  
                     "lastFeedSearch":{  
                        "$lte": "2015-06-16T06:52:30+00:00"
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "lastFeedSearch":{  
                        "$exists": false
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, all these `$or` conditions should at least match.
From what I can tell, it's because the `$exists` doesn't seem to take `null` values into account, although the documentation says it should.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MongoDB official `$exists` docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#definition):

> When **<boolean>** is true, **$exists** matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is **null**. If **<boolean>** is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field.

In other words, `$exists` count `null`s as valid values. So, `{"$exists": false}` only matches documents where corresponding field is `undefined`, not `null`.

Try matching your fields with `null` instead:

```
{
    "lastTopicSearch": null
}
```

This query will match both `null` and `undefined` values.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation of $exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) says:

> When `<boolean>` is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null. If  is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field.

All your conditions have `$exists:false`. Your document has the mentioned fields (with a value of `null`), so the document does not get returned.

Unfortunately you can not to `{ endDate: null }` because that would also match documents where the field doesn't exist (unless the query uses a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) for that field).

[When your want to find documents where the field is null](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls) and you don't want to create a sparse index, search for fields where *the type* of the field is `Null` using the [$type-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

```
{ endDate : { $type: 10 } }
```

Comment: I noticed that just using `endDate: null` didn't work when it didn't exist. Your answer however did gave me a good idea of how to solve it: http://pastebin.com/H1ds7GQw

Comment: @woutr_be There was a factual error in an earlier version of this answer. I changed it considerably.

Comment: did notice that, however using `$type: 10` doesn't seem to work when the field doesn't exist.